# How do I reinstall the preinstalled bluetooth program?

Tags: bluetooth, unity-tweak-tool

I tried to install the Unity Tweak Tool but it said I needed [the Bluetooth app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaCFD.jpg) that comes preinstalled that I uninstalled. Now I can't find a way to reinstall it.

Comment: try `apt-get install bluez`.

Answer (score 1):

Install the package "indicator-bluetooth" using `sudo apt-get install indicator-bluetooth`.